Unable to create a python socket listener inside a docker container
I’ve created a docker image that runs a ROS1 rospy project. This project is run on a mobile robot that connects to the onboard computer running the image container. In order to communicate properly, the container needs to open a socket listener that binds to an ip. The ip in question is the gateway ip of the tag (the onboard computer). The issue is that for whatever reason the socket creation fails when running inside the container, but not when running natively.
heres the line in question :
self.socket_listener = SocketListener(MOBILE_BASE_CONFIGS[“omron_tag_gateway_ip”],
MOBILE_BASE_CONFIGS[“arcl_status_port”],
MOBILE_BASE_CONFIGS[“arcl_socket_receive_buffer”],
MOBILE_BASE_CONFIGS[“max_communication_retries”])


I’ve tried running both with docker compose and with docker run and in both case it wont work.
The container and the exterior are able to communicate since it is able to connect to the tag ethernet ip and communicate to the robot base, but it simply wont open a socket listener.
The specific error is Erno99 - cannot assign requested address.
I can show dockerfile, compose file and docker run command if needed. Thanks in advance.
I tried both docker compose and docker run and not in a container. only the last one works.

Within a Docker container, the IP addresses will be different unless you use --net=host, so it stands to reason that you can't listen on an IP address that is only known to the host.
You could just listen on all interfaces with 0.0.0.0:
self.socket_listener = SocketListener(
    "0.0.0.0",
    MOBILE_BASE_CONFIGS["arcl_status_port"],
    MOBILE_BASE_CONFIGS["arcl_socket_receive_buffer"],
    MOBILE_BASE_CONFIGS["max_communication_retries"],
)

Then you'll need to -publish that port to the host, so the Docker machinery can forward requests from outside the container to that port.
The other option, as implied above, is --net=host, so there is no network isolation. That'll probably be OK for your use case.

I am already using network=host which is why this behavior confuses me, but I will give the 0.0.0.0. approach a try
